# Using structure created in plist and store user input into memory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, plist

I am trying to work on an iPhone application.

I am wondering if it is possible to use a structure that I have created and defined in the plist (either using the plist editor/etc) and store user's input using that structure into the iPhone memory. Is it possible? If so, how do I go about doing that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should just make a class that contains the structure...

Comment: How do I go about doing that?? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read plists, if that's what you mean?

```
NSDictionary *plist = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"yourPlistFile"] propertyList];
```

Comment: Yup, I can read plist, but how do I store user's input into memory using the plist structure?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "user's input" and "plist structure"?

Comment: Like, I define let's say, I want to store user input and store them into the memory instead of plist. But, I will define a structure like NSArray within NSDictionary (etc) in the plist. Is it possible? Sorry that I don't phrase the question well! Thanks for helping!!

Comment: So, basically you wan't to create classes from a plist? That isn't possible ... Just code them in Objective-C ...

Comment: So actually the plist part is useless?